# AccessDenied being encountered while using UploadPartCopy to MultiPartUpload in Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am attempting to use S3 MultipartUpload to concat files in an S3 bucket.  If you have several files >5MB (the last file can be smaller), you can concatenate them in S3 into a larger file.  It's basically the equivalent of using `cat` to merge files together.  When I attempt to do this in Go, I get:

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the UploadPartCopy operation: Access Denied`

The code looks kind of like this:

```
mpuOut, err := s3CreateMultipartUpload(&S3.CreateMultipartUploadInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(concatenatedFile),
})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

var ps []*S3.CompletedPart
for i, part := range parts { // parts is a list of paths to things in s3
    partNumber := int64(i) + 1
    upOut, err := s3UploadPartCopy(&S3.UploadPartCopyInput{
        Bucket:     aws.String(bucket),
        CopySource: aws.String(part),
        Key:        aws.String(concatenatedFile),
        UploadId:   aws.String(*mpuOut.UploadId),
        PartNumber: aws.Int64(partNumber),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err // <- fails here
    }
    ps = append(ps, &S3.CompletedPart{
        ETag:       s3Out.CopyPartResult.ETag,
        PartNumber: aws.Int64(int64(i)),
    })
}

_, err = s3CompleteMultipartUpload(&S3.CompleteMultipartUploadInput{
    Bucket:          aws.String(bucket),
    Key:             aws.String(concatenatedFile),
    MultipartUpload: &S3.CompletedMultipartUpload{Parts: ps},
    UploadId:        aws.String(*mpuOut.UploadId),
})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

_, err = s3CompleteMultipartUpload(&S3.CompleteMultipartUploadInput{
    Bucket:          aws.String(bucket),
    Key:             aws.String(concatenatedFile),
    MultipartUpload: &S3.CompletedMultipartUpload{Parts: ps},
    UploadId:        aws.String(*mpuOut.UploadId),
})
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

When it runs, it blows up with the error above.  The permissions on the bucket are wide open.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so the problem is that when you are doing a UploadPartCopy, for the CopySource parameter, you don't just use the path in the s3 bucket.  You have to put the buckname at the front of the path, even if it is in the same bucket.  Derp

```
mpuOut, err := s3CreateMultipartUpload(&S3.CreateMultipartUploadInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(concatenatedFile),
})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

var ps []*S3.CompletedPart
for i, part := range parts { // parts is a list of paths to things in s3
    partNumber := int64(i) + 1
    upOut, err := s3UploadPartCopy(&S3.UploadPartCopyInput{
        Bucket:     aws.String(bucket),
        CopySource: aws.String(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", bucket, part), // <- ugh
        Key:        aws.String(concatenatedFile),
        UploadId:   aws.String(*mpuOut.UploadId),
        PartNumber: aws.Int64(partNumber),
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    ps = append(ps, &S3.CompletedPart{
        ETag:       s3Out.CopyPartResult.ETag,
        PartNumber: aws.Int64(int64(i)),
    })
}

_, err = s3CompleteMultipartUpload(&S3.CompleteMultipartUploadInput{
    Bucket:          aws.String(bucket),
    Key:             aws.String(concatenatedFile),
    MultipartUpload: &S3.CompletedMultipartUpload{Parts: ps},
    UploadId:        aws.String(*mpuOut.UploadId),
})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

_, err = s3CompleteMultipartUpload(&S3.CompleteMultipartUploadInput{
    Bucket:          aws.String(bucket),
    Key:             aws.String(concatenatedFile),
    MultipartUpload: &S3.CompletedMultipartUpload{Parts: ps},
    UploadId:        aws.String(*mpuOut.UploadId),
})
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

This just wasted about an hour of my life, so I figure I would try to save someone else the trouble.